# X.Org error in Kubuntu on MacPro

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, radeon, mac, amdgpu

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) on my Mac Pro (Trashcan).

With out `nomodeset` in the boot parameters, X.Org terminates upon startup.
The display switches back and forth between one working tty2 and one corrupted tty about every 3 seconds.
The tail of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is…

```
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
[   161.049] (EE) RADEON(G0): failed to initialise surface manager
[   161.049] (EE) RADEON(G0): radeon_setup_kernel_mem failed
[   161.049] (EE) Fatal server error:
[   161.049] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for gpu driver 0 -1
[   161.049] (EE) 
[   161.049] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
[   161.049] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   161.049] (EE) 
[   161.068] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

…but, further up are the lines…

```
[   160.104] (II) Applying OutputClass "Radeon" to /dev/dri/card0
[   160.104]    loading driver: radeon
[   160.104] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card1
[   160.104]    loading driver: amdgpu
```

Where as there are 2 identical video cards, shouldn’t the same driver be used for both?

When booting with `nomodeset` in the boot parameters, I can get x.org to run and allow me to open a terminal windows.
When doing so and running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` I get

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
--
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
06:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
```

Also, looking at the `/var/log/syslog` the word ‘segfault’ appears 32 times, ‘error’ 92 times, ‘fail’ 195….
Is this normal?

Details below…

Kubuntu 17.04 64 bit for desktop installed into a USB3 drive from a bootable USB stick.

Mac Pro (Late 2013) aka MacPro6,1

2 AMD FirePro D300 video graphics cards (Pitcairn-based GPU) which have been referred to as “in essence the W7000 but with half the VRAM” https://architosh.com/2013/10/the-mac-pro-so-whats-a-d300-d500-and-d700-anyway-we-have-answers/

full `Xorg.O.log`

```
[   160.090] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
[   160.090] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   160.090] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   160.091] Current Operating System: Linux hans-MacPro 4.10.0-32-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 12:10:06 UTC 2017 x86_64
[   160.091] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/sdb2
[   160.091] Build Date: 28 March 2017  06:16:52AM
[   160.091] xorg-server 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   160.091] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   160.091]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   160.091] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   160.091] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 17 16:59:42 2017
[   160.091] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   160.091] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   160.091] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   160.091] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   160.091] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   160.091] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   160.091] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   160.091] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   160.091] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   160.092] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   160.092] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   160.092] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   160.092]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.092] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   160.092]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.092] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   160.092]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.092] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   160.092]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.092] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   160.092]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.092] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   160.092] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   160.092] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   160.092] (II) Loader magic: 0x56343af47020
[   160.092] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   160.092]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   160.092]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   160.092]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   160.092]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   160.093] (++) using VT number 7

[   160.093] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   160.094] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   160.096] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   160.102] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 1002:6810:106b:012b rev 0, Mem @ 0x80000000/268435456, 0xa0700000/262144, I/O @ 0x00003000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   160.102] (--) PCI:*(0:6:0:0) 1002:6810:106b:012a rev 0, Mem @ 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0600000/262144, I/O @ 0x00002000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   160.102] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   160.103] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   160.104] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.104]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.104]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   160.104] (II) Applying OutputClass "Radeon" to /dev/dri/card0
[   160.104]    loading driver: radeon
[   160.104] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card1
[   160.104]    loading driver: amdgpu
[   160.104] (==) Matched radeon as autoconfigured driver 0
[   160.104] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[   160.104] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 2
[   160.104] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[   160.104] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 4
[   160.104] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[   160.104] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[   160.104] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 7
[   160.104] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   160.104] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[   160.104] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[   160.104] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.104]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 7.9.0
[   160.104]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.104]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.105] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   160.105] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   160.105] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.105]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 7.9.0
[   160.105]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.105]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.164] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   160.164] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   160.165] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.165]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.3.0
[   160.165]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.165]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.165] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   160.165] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   160.165] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.165]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.19.3
[   160.165]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.165]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.165] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   160.166] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   160.166] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.166]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[   160.166]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.166]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.166] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   160.166] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   160.166] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.166]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[   160.166]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.166]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.166] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon chipsets:
    ATI Radeon Mobility X600 (M24), ATI FireMV 2400,
...skipping for space...
AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series, AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series, TURKS, CAICOS,
    ARUBA, TAHITI, PITCAIRN, VERDE, OLAND, HAINAN, BONAIRE, KABINI,
    MULLINS, KAVERI, HAWAII
[   160.169] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[   160.169] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   160.169] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   160.169] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   160.180] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[   160.180] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[   160.180] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   160.180] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   160.180] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   160.180] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   160.180] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   160.181] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.181]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.0.2
[   160.181]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   160.181] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   160.181] (II) RADEON(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   160.181] (==) RADEON(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   160.181] (II) RADEON(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   160.181] (==) RADEON(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   160.181] (==) RADEON(0): RGB weight 888
[   160.181] (II) RADEON(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[   160.181] (--) RADEON(0): Chipset: "PITCAIRN" (ChipID = 0x6810)
[   160.181] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   160.181] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   160.181] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   160.182] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.182]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.182]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   160.182] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   160.182] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   160.182] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   160.182] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   160.182] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   160.182] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   160.189] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.189]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.189]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   160.189] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[   160.231] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4 (DRI2):
[   160.234] (II) RADEON(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[   160.234] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Color Tiling: enabled
[   160.234] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Color Tiling 2D: enabled
[   160.234] (==) RADEON(0): TearFree property default: auto
[   160.234] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[   160.265] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-0 has no monitor section
[   160.297] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-1 has no monitor section
[   160.348] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-2 has no monitor section
[   160.381] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-3 has no monitor section
[   160.413] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-4 has no monitor section
[   160.445] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-5 has no monitor section
[   160.477] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[   160.509] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-2
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer: ACR  Model: 2c5  Serial#: 855642923
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Year: 2013  Week: 30
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Digital Display Input
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 52  vert.: 32
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): redX: 0.647 redY: 0.331   greenX: 0.314 greenY: 0.621
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.070   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Supported established timings:
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 720x400@70Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@60Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@67Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@72Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@56Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@60Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@72Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 832x624@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): 1152x864@75Hz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Supported standard timings:
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #4: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): #5: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): clock: 154.0 MHz   Image Size:  518 x 324 mm
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1968  h_sync_end 2000 h_blank_end 2080 h_border: 0
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): v_active: 1200  v_sync: 1203  v_sync_end 1209 v_blanking: 1235 v_border: 0
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 185 MHz
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Serial No: LV6AA0014239
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Monitor name: Acer B243PWL
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): EDID (in hex):
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    00ffffffffffff000472c5022b130033
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    1e170103803420782af8c5a554509f26
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    125054bfef80714f8180814081c08100
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    b30001010101283c80a070b023403020
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    360006442100001a000000fd00384b1e
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    5312000a202020202020000000ff004c
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    56364141303031343233390a000000fc
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0):    0041636572204232343350574c0a00eb
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Printing probed modes for output DisplayPort-2
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x60.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.9   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   160.560] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[   160.561] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[   160.561] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   160.561] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[   160.561] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   160.561] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   160.593] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-3
[   160.625] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-4
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-5
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-0 disconnected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-1 disconnected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-2 connected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-3 disconnected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-4 disconnected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-5 disconnected
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-2 using initial mode 1920x1200 +0+0
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(0): mem size init: gart size :7fbcc000 vram size: s:80000000 visible:f15e000
[   160.657] (==) RADEON(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   160.657] (==) RADEON(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   160.657] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   160.657] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   160.657] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   160.657] (==) RADEON(G0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(G0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   160.657] (==) RADEON(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   160.657] (==) RADEON(G0): RGB weight 888
[   160.657] (II) RADEON(G0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[   160.657] (--) RADEON(G0): Chipset: "PITCAIRN" (ChipID = 0x6810)
[   160.657] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   160.657] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   160.658] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   160.658] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.658]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.658]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   160.658] (II) RADEON(G0): Kernel too old missing accel information, assuming accel is working
[   160.658] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   160.658] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   160.658] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   160.658] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   160.658] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   160.658] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   160.658] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.658]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.658]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   160.658] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[   160.664] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4 (DRI2):
[   160.666] (II) RADEON(G0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[   160.666] (II) RADEON(G0): KMS Color Tiling: disabled
[   160.666] (II) RADEON(G0): KMS Color Tiling 2D: enabled
[   160.666] (==) RADEON(G0): TearFree property default: auto
[   160.696] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-6 has no monitor section
[   160.728] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-7 has no monitor section
[   160.760] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-8 has no monitor section
[   160.793] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-9 has no monitor section
[   160.824] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-10 has no monitor section
[   160.857] (II) RADEON(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-11 has no monitor section
[   160.888] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-6
[   160.920] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-7
[   160.953] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-8
[   160.985] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-9
[   161.017] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-10
[   161.048] (II) RADEON(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-11
[   161.049] (==) RADEON(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   161.049] (==) RADEON(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   161.049] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   161.049] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   161.049] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   161.049] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[   161.049] (II) Unloading amdgpu
[   161.049] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   161.049] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   161.049] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   161.049] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   161.049] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   161.049] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   161.049] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   161.049] (II) Unloading vesa
[   161.049] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
[   161.049] (II) RADEON(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
[   161.049] (EE) RADEON(G0): failed to initialise surface manager
[   161.049] (EE) RADEON(G0): radeon_setup_kernel_mem failed
[   161.049] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   161.049] (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for gpu driver 0 -1
[   161.049] (EE) 
[   161.049] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   161.049] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   161.049] (EE) 
[   161.068] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

...9/7/2017
This same problem occurs in 16.04.3 LTS, but then it gets weird.
Screen switches to blank and back 3 times fast then ok for 1.5 seconds.
Keyboard only responds to magic keys when NOT blank.
Magic key U stops the blinking and stabilizes the system when at tty.
The weird part is if I repeatedly try to reboot into the system, it will boot into a fine working system once every 4th to 6th try?!
How do you debug that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Boot with nomodeset and then get the output?

The system is inoperable with out it.  The terminal just jumps back and forth.

Comment: @H.P.Z. Yes, as usual. It has no bearing on the results of the requested command

Comment: On a hunch I blacklisted `amdgpu` driver per [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360709/how-to-blacklist-amdgpu) and then rebooted.  The system came up fine except for an effective response rate of 2Hz.   
Attempted the same blacklisting of `radeon` but then the system would not boot.  Had to go into recovery mode to set it back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can say that Kubuntu 16.04.3 is compatible with MacPro6,1 only when installed and run with `nomodeset` in the kernel parameters (or if one is willing to reboot over and over again until it comes up by chance).

Kubuntu 17.04 is the same but (may) began working normally when the kernel is updated to 4.10.0-33-generic.

Details for adding `nomodeset` as kernel parameter my be found at  [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue on my Mac Pro at work, which uses an AMD Southern Islands graphics chip (PCI 1002:679e). Specifically, I get:

> failed to initialise surface manager / radeon_setup_kernel_mem failed

and then xorg terminates.

The screen blinking is due to sddm crashing and restarting in an infinite loop [since it can't connect to xorg](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/599). You can find more details using

```
dmesg | grep -i sddm
```

and generate a proper backtrace using gdb. (sddm really ought to have better error reporting in this instance.)

For me, the issue went away after upgrading to kernel 4.13.0.